# Use of caps for zip code

Tags: capitalization, proper-nouns, acronyms

I would like to know which of "ZIP Code" or "ZIP code" is correct. One of our contributors has alerted me to the  fact that the term is a registered name owned by the US Postal Service, but, to my mind, it has become a generic term over time. What is the majority view?

Comment: I see ZIP code commonly used in (web) forms aimed at European customers, meaning that it _is_ used to describe a different routing system from the US-native one (whoever created it). _Postal code_ is used as well, but I have not often, if ever, heard complaint about ZIP code.

Comment: Majority by who?   Web developers?  Newspaper style guides?  Randon people on the web?

Comment: A term cannot become generic unless it is used for goods or services that are created by someone other than the trademark owner. Unless ZIP Code is used to describe a different routing system created by (not just used by) FedEx or UPS or Dan's Delivery Service, it is not generic. The USPS did allow the registration to expire in 1997, but that does not mean it cannot continue to exert common law rights over the trademark.

Comment: I just checked the Oxford English Dictionary and Merriam Webster and both use "zip code" as the first entry and add, "also ZIP code". In neither case do they capitalize "code", so I guess the term can in fact be used generically. Though you have a point: the article specifically refers to the U.S., but I suspect the only party who may notice is the Postal Service itself. Oddly, ZIP stands for zoning improvement plan, so the dictionaries' usage is even more surprising.

Comment: oerkelens, *postcode* is used in the UK http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/british/postcode?q=postcode

Comment: Oerkelens: the same dictionary you refer to contains the term "zip code": http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/british/zip-code?q=zip+code

Comment: _Zipcode_, or just _zip_, are both very common in the language. I'd say the USPS has no "common-law" rights to exert over the term, except in how it presents it. In any event, this is a spelling question, and is only relevant in writing, not language. It's pronounced as if it were spelled _zipcode_. Caps are normally not audible.

Comment: Note: I am proof-reading an article for an academic journal, so I would like the "spelling" to be correct.

Comment: @JohnLawler Are you suggesting we only concern ourselves with the spoken language? Should all 664 questions on orthography be closed and deleted?

Comment: I'm suggesting that problems unique to the written language are not problems about English Language and Usage; they normally have to do with the dumb tricks previous generations have come up with to work around using Middle English spelling for a different language. Steampunk technology, not language. The real language is spoken, and if that is taken into consideration, irrelevancies like spelling, punctuation, and capitalization tend to fade away.

Answer (score 7):

I checked a few standard U.S. style guides from the past to see how they handled the term *ZIP/Zip/zip Code/code*. In discussing the two-letter abbreviations of the various states, *Words Into Type*, Third Edition (1974) cites "the ZIP (Zone Improvement Program) code" for each abbreviation.

In contrast, Merriam-Webster's *Ninth Collegiate Dictionary* (1983) has this entry:

> **zip code** *n*, *often cap Z&I&P* [zone improvement plan] (1963) a number that identifies each postal delivery area in the U.S.

*The Chicago Manual of Style*, Fourteenth Edition (1993) observes that "the two-letter form [of state abbreviations] is specified by the United States government for use with zip code addresses in mailing."

Perhaps the most baffling element here is the failure to agree on what *zip* stands for. A colloquy between Senator Absalom Robertson of Virginia and a Mr. McMillan of the Post Office Department during a [hearing on appropriations](http://books.google.com/books?id=TRg3AQAAIAAJ&q=%22zone+improvement+program%22&dq=%22zone+improvement+program%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=wSCOU5zEC9CgogTwuIDYAg&ved=0CC4Q6AEwAQ) for the next fiscal year seems dispositive [snippet]:

> Senator ROBERTSON. Do I understand that "ZIP" stands for zone improvement program?
>
> Mr. McMILLAN. Yes, sir, zone improvement program.

Various official government publications from the mid-1960s support this understanding of the name—but an approximately equal number of contemporaneous government publications identify *ZIP* as being short for "Zone Improvement Plan." Not surprisingly, the confusion trickled down to the private sector. The March 1968 issue of *[Changing Times](http://books.google.com/books?id=fgAEAAAAMBAJ&pg=PA23&dq=%22zone+improvement+plan%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=ZSWOU6_gBM7doATfloLYBQ&ved=0CDAQ6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=%22zone%20improvement%20plan%22&f=false)* ("The Kiplinger Service for Families") has this item:

> **Zip.** Those five code numbers are very important to the delivery of your mail. So make an effort to use them. The zip (Zone Improvement Plan) system expedites handling and reduces errors, helping you and the post office.

But four months later, in discussing the Post Office's cartoon mascot Mr. ZIP, *[Changing Times](http://books.google.com/books?id=DQEEAAAAMBAJ&pg=PA32&dq=%22zone+improvement+program%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=mCSOU8rVMMaHogTExoLgCg&ved=0CCoQ6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=%22zone%20improvement%20program%22&f=false)* included this note:

> At first the figure was called "Mr. P.O. Zone." But the name was soon changed to "Mr. ZIP." (ZIP stands for Zone Improvement Program.)

An [Ngram graph](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=zone+improvement+program%2Czone+improvement+plan%2C+Zone+Improvement+Plan%2C+Zone+Improvement+Program&case_insensitive=on&year_start=1960&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=0&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2CZone%20Improvement%20Program%3B%2Cc0%3B.t4%3B%2Czone%20improvement%20plan%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3BZone%20Improvement%20Plan%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bzone%20improvement%20plan%3B%2Cc0%3B.t4%3B%2CZone%20Improvement%20Plan%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3BZone%20Improvement%20Plan%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bzone%20improvement%20plan%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2CZone%20Improvement%20Program%3B%2Cc0) based on Google Search results for the past 50 years suggests that for most of that time, "Zone Improvement Plan" has been significantly more popular than "Zone Improvement Program." But considering how unsure the government itself seems to have been as to what the acronym *zip* stood for, it is hardly surprising that Merriam-Webster's (for one) would be inclined to identify "zone improvement plan" as a lowercase description rather than as an initial-capped official name. Nor is it surprising, given the Postal Service's emphasis on the swiftness of mail delivery that was sure to ensue following adoption of the new five-number codes, that *ZIP* itself became popularly understood not as an acronym at all but as a (lowercase) descriptive term.

Currently, Merriam-Webster's and Chicago favor "zip code," while the AP Stylebook continues to prefer "ZIP code"; none of these references capitalizes the *c* in *code*.

Comment: “Z&I&P”? That doesn't look quite right…

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet: The wording "_often cap Z&I&P_" is Merriam-Webster shorthand for "often spelled with a capital Z, a capital I, and a capital P"—or in other words, "often spelled _ZIP_ rather than _zip_." Awkward though the usage note's wording may be, Merriam-Webster repeated it in the tenth (1993) and eleventh (2003) editions of the Collegiate Dictionary.

Answer (score 4):

This is another of those cases where opinions and style guides vary, and the writer should strive above all for consistency.

As elsewhere noted, *ZIP Code* is a U.S. Postal Service trademark, and originates with the *Zone Improvement Plan*. This is the orthography still preferred by the USPS, as indicated in its official [mailing guidelines](http://about.usps.com/publications/pub177.pdf), as used throughout its website, and as found in official accounts such as *[The Untold Story of the ZIP Code](https://www.uspsoig.gov/sites/default/files/document-library-files/2013/rarc-wp-13-006.pdf)*. The expanded program is known as *ZIP+4* or *ZIP Code+4*— though addresses using it are described as *ZIP+4-coded*.

The legal genericization or lack thereof of *ZIP Code*, I think, is irrelevant. *ZIP Code* is the original and arguably most accurate form, but such things change over time. Many argue for *Web site* over *website*, since it is not just any web, but *the World Wide Web*, yet even the Associated Press finally threw in the towel on that one not long ago; the all-lowercase single word *[website](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=Web%20site,web%20site,website&year_start=1990&year_end=2010&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1;,Web%20site;,c0;.t1;,web%20site;,c0;.t1;,website;,c0)* is prevalent.

FWIW, the 2008 U.S. Government Printing Office style guide [lists *ZIP Code*](http://www.gpo.gov/fdsys/pkg/GPO-STYLEMANUAL-2008/pdf/GPO-STYLEMANUAL-2008-6.pdf) as its preferred capitalization. But the GPO does not dictate style for anyone outside the GPO, even other agencies of the federal government. AP and the [HHS website](http://www.hhs.gov/web/policies/webstyle.html), among others, call for all-caps *ZIP* but lowercase *code*. The University of California, Berkeley style guide stipulates [lowercase *zip code*](http://identity.berkeley.edu/guidelines/berkeley-editorial-style-09.pdf).

As it happens, Google Books shows *zip code* far outpolling *ZIP Code*, *ZIP code*, *Zip code*, and *zipcode* by a good measure even in the early days of the program.

[image: "zip code" is far more popular than alternatively capitalized forms]

(As a low-incidence term, the unusual spikes may result from quirks in the volumes represented in Google Books; for example, they could reflect a change in a government style guide, and government documents might be overrepresented for recent decades.)

Comment: I'm guessing the reason "zip code" is so popular is because it's easier to type and most of us know Google will give equivalent results either way.